# Navigation bar, header and footer of bootstrap, common to all pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am using Bootstrap for designing web application. I have used navigation bar, header and footer in my home page. Now i want all those to be available for all web pages without rewriting the same code again and again everywhere. what should be done to get that.

Comment: For clarification, I am using bootstrap in jsp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make two Jsp Pages header.jsp and footer.jsp. which contains respective code.
and include these pages in every where by using jsp:include

```
 e.g <jsp:include="header.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, with MVC you put all of that in your _layout file. See [this tutorial](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-3-with-asp-net-mvc-5).

Inside the _layout file you have:

```
<div class="container">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

which renders everything between the header/nav and the footer (whatever is in your index file).

Example:

[image: _layout example]

Answer (score 0):

You have to make them a separate file like `header.php` and `footer.php` and
and all of this included in your `index.php` file

Answer (score 0):

You better use `templates` for `navigation bar, header and footer`

At first create a folder `templates` and make `header-template.html` inside the template folder and include it in that page where you want it like

```
include /templates/header-template.html
```

and the rest of your code.

Do the above for `navigation bar` and for `footer` also..
Hope this helps..